# Parse.com Android - ObjectId is null/blank

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm querying parse.com but for some reason I cannot get the `objectId` however I can get the other values. Any idea why I cannot retrieve the objectId?

I've tried `getObjectId()` and also `get("objectId"`) to no avail.

Here is some code

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dates_main);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Schedule");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {

            if (e == null) {
                for (ParseObject object : objects) {

                    Log.d("App", "object id: " + object.getObjectId());
                    Log.d("App", "object updated at: " + object.getUpdatedAt());
                    Log.d("App", "object created at: " + object.getCreatedAt());
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The output:

```
D/App: object updated at: Sun Oct 11 22:12:38 EDT 2015
D/App: object created at: Sat Oct 10 17:02:43 EDT 2015
D/App: object id: 
D/App: object updated at: Sat Dec 19 10:34:38 EST 2015
D/App: object created at: Sat Oct 10 17:11:18 EDT 2015
D/App: object id: 
D/App: object updated at: Sun Dec 20 17:37:59 EST 2015
D/App: object created at: Sun Dec 20 17:33:44 EST 2015
D/App: object id: 
D/App: object updated at: Thu Jan 07 19:31:05 EST 2016
D/App: object created at: Thu Jan 07 19:30:37 EST 2016
```

Comment: What version of parse SDK?

Comment: Parse 1.12.0 is the version I'm using

Comment: Save is async . if it's really done, in Android , you should have non-null I'd value.

Comment: I'm not saving anything, I'm fetching from Parse.com. The objectId is there but it can't be retrieved in code for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

My Schedule class had an objectId in there and since ParseObject already has an objectId, it kept referencing this one thus the blank

```
@ParseClassName("Schedule")
public class Schedule extends ParseObject {
     String objectId = "";
     ...
}
```

That objectId needs to be removed!